# Multiclass U-Net segmentation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I've seen variations of this question all over, but am still struggling to implement it correctly.  I have brain MRI images with ground-truth segmented masks with 4 classes (0- background, 1-tissue type1, 2-tissue type2, 3-inexplicably skipped, and 4-tissue type 4...BrATs dataset)

[image]

I have a basic U-Net architecture implemented, but am having trouble extending it to non-binary classification.  Particularly, the loss function.

This is what I have implemented, but I'm obviously overlooking important details:

```
[...]
output = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(
conv18,
filters=5,
kernel_size=1,
strides=1,
padding='same',
data_format='channels_last',
activation=None,
use_bias=True,
kernel_initializer=None,
bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(reg),
bias_regularizer=None,
activity_regularizer=None,
kernel_constraint=None,
bias_constraint=None,
trainable=True,
name='output',
reuse=None
)
```

I thought 5 filters for the (0,1,2,3,4) possible mask values would be correct.  I then used the following loss function:

```
loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
_sentinel=None,
labels=label,
logits=output,
name='cross_ent_loss'
)

return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

Where the logits would get passed the output from above, and the labels would be my stacked mask images [n_batch, x_dim, y_dim, 1]. Looking at the documentation, I know I am not passing labels the correct tensor.

Am I even going about this correctly?  How do I implement the loss with multi-class labels contained within the 1 mask image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I overlooked straight from the documentation 
[tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits):

> labels: Tensor of shape [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}] (where r is rank of labels and result) and dtype int32 or int64. Each entry in labels must be an index in [0, num_classes). Other values will raise an exception when this op is run on CPU, and return NaN for corresponding loss and gradient rows on GPU.

So changing the labels to shape [-1]

```
label_reshape = tf.reshape(label, [-1])
```

fixed it!